# Using TextJoin in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to `TextJoin` in Access, I was able to complete this in Excel for a entire row by using the below formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,F2:F251)
```

How do I replicate this in Access?

Comment: You want to join texts of different fields but same record?

Answer (score 0):

MS Access uses a completely different paradigm to Excel. There is no way of doing this without handcrafting it in VBA code.

Loop through the recordset rows and concatenate the column values to a variable. You can't really rely on the column order being correct in a for/next loop so you might have to refer to the columns by name.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for people trying to replicate TextJoin on Access:

```
Function TextJoin(Separator As String, List As Variant) As String
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    For Each Item In List
        TextJoin = TextJoin & Item & Separator
    Next Item
    
    TextJoin = Left(TextJoin, Len(TextJoin) - Len(Separator))
End Function
```

List parameter is expected to be an array of strings.

Example of usage:

```
>>> Debug.Print TextJoin(" | ", Array("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow"))
Blue | Red | Green | Yellow
```

If you have any additional doubt, feel free to ask :)